# Sql Subquery IN clause returns all rows even if not match where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am just filtering users who first name has if column 'src'='L'

I know we can filter by just doing `SELECT * from users where src ='L'`

But I just tried with sub query `SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname in (SELECT firstname  from users where src ='L')`   its returning all 'L' and 'S' rows

Table Data :

```
 create table users (id integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100),src varchar(100));

    insert into users (id, firstname, lastname,src) values
    (1, 'albert', 'einstein','L'),
    (2, 'isaac', 'newton','S'),
    (3, 'marie', 'curie','L'),
    (4, 'isaac', 'newton','L');
```

Ideally both queries should return Only 'L' records. I am not sql expert Can any one explain difference.

But if I delete id 4 then both queries returns only L or S records

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the desired result, but note that a dataset comprising just 4 rows is rarely enough to be representative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery is returning `isaac` as first name who actually has two rows for source 'L' and 'S'. If you want to get same result as subquery then it's better to join subquery with outer query through id column instead of firstName since id column is unique.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id in (SELECT id  from users where src ='L')
```

I assume that you are trying to learn SQL. So I am sharing here another approach of doing it with `exists` instead of `in`

```
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE 
exists (SELECT 1  from users usr where src ='L' and u.id=usr.id)
```

All the queries in DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table users (id integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100),src varchar(100));
 
     insert into users (id, firstname, lastname,src) values
     (1, 'albert', 'einstein','L'),
     (2, 'isaac', 'newton','S'),
     (3, 'marie', 'curie','L'),
     (4, 'isaac', 'newton','L');
```

Query with in:

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE id in (SELECT id  from users where src ='L')
```

Output:

| id | firstname | lastname | src |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | albert | einstein | L |
| 3 | marie | curie | L |
| 4 | isaac | newton | L |

Query with exists:

```
 SELECT * FROM users u WHERE 
 exists (SELECT 1  from users usr where src ='L' and u.id=usr.id)
```

Output:

| id | firstname | lastname | src |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | albert | einstein | L |
| 3 | marie | curie | L |
| 4 | isaac | newton | L |

Subquery:

```
 SELECT firstname  from users where src ='L'
```

| firstname |
| --- |
| albert |
| marie |
| isaac |

Query to select all rows WHERE FirstName='isaac'

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE FirstName='isaac'
```

Output:

| id | firstname | lastname | src |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | isaac | newton | S |
| 4 | isaac | newton | L |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3df275b6a0a6f2c33c69e3ded22624e0)*

Comment: Yeah this is perfect !!. But if we execute sub query separately (`SELECT firstname  from users where src ='L'`) then it returns only L records . not Isaac two times .. I believe main query will select from result of sub query right

Comment: Main query will select FirstName from subquery then it will just use this in where condition. For isaac your MainQuery would be `SELECT * FROM users WHERE FirstName='isaac'` which will select both the rows for isaac since in Main query you didn't use `src ='L'` condition in where clause.

Comment: You are most welcome @VyasReddy. If it helped then please accept this answer by clicking the green check. Thanks. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

The second query returns all firstname where there is at least one record from `src = 'L'`.

The first just returns rows where `src = 'L'`.

These are not the same.  Firstnames could have multiple rows in the table, some of which are from L and some are not.

Answer (score 0):

Subquery returns:

```
mysql> SELECT firstname  from users where src ='L';
+-----------+
| firstname |
+-----------+
| albert    |
| marie     |
| isaac     |
+-----------+
```

Main query returns all rows with firstname in that list. You have two rows with isaac, all works fine.

You need to change your logic and add `src` check in main query.

Comment: But if I delete id 4 then both queries returns only L or S records

Comment: `SELECT firstname  from users where src ='L';`
returns:  `albert ,  marie `

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname in (SELECT firstname  from users where src ='L');`

return 1 and 3, not 2 (issac).

Your MAIN query check ONLY firstname, not src. If you delete id4, than subquery returns uniq number of firstname for src.

Answer (score 0):

My better understanding for this question

```
 Main Query : Select * users 
    +-----+-----------+----------+-----+
    | id  | firstname | lastname | src |
    +-----+-----------+----------+-----+
    |  1  | albert    | einstein |  L  |
    |  2  | isaac     | newton   |  S  |
    |  3  | marie     | curie    |  L  |
    |  4  | isaac     | newton   |  L  |
    +-----+-----------+----------+-----+

 Sub Query : SELECT firstname  from users where src ='L'
    +-----+-----------+----------+-----+
    | id  | firstname | lastname | src |
    +-----+-----------+----------+-----+
    |  1  | albert    | einstein |  L  |
    |                                  |
    |  3  | marie     | curie    |  L  |
    |  4  | isaac     | newton   |  L  |
    +-----+-----------+----------+-----+

  Where Id 2 firstname(isaac) is in Sub Query result Id 4 of firstname, 
  So Its true to returns all rows

    +-----+-----------+----------+-----+
    | id  | firstname | lastname | src |
    +-----+-----------+----------+-----+
    |  1  | albert    | einstein |  L  |
    |  2  | isaac     | newton   |  S  |
    |  3  | marie     | curie    |  L  |
    |  4  | isaac     | newton   |  L  |
    +-----+-----------+----------+-----+
```